# How do the following statements imply uniform integrability

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory

I'm reading a paper and there is a statement that $(1)$ and $(2)$ below imply uniform integrability of $\log \xi_n$. Context is not necessary but if interested, I'm looking at Page $22$, $2^{nd}$ paragraph [here](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwjspuOT9fLpAhW6JjQIHXYiAJMQFjAAegQIBBAB&url=https%3A%2F%2Farxiv.org%2Fabs%2F1611.01079&usg=AOvVaw1r5eStCfwGvrFQAqOa3EeM).

Lemma $15$: $$\sup_{n\geq 1}\mathbb{E}\left[\exp \left(\lambda\sum_{j=1}^n P_n(1,j)^\beta \right) \right]<\infty \tag{1}$$
Equation $(60):$
$$\sum_{j=1}^n P_n(1,j)\log P_n(1,j)^2\leq (\log \epsilon)^2+\sup_{p\in [0,\epsilon]}p^{1-\beta}(\log p)^2\sum_{j=1}^n P(1,j)^\beta \tag{2}$$

where $0\leq P_n(1,j)\leq 1$ are random variables and $\mathbb{E} \sum_{j=1}^n P_n(1,j)\log P_n(1,j) = \mathbb{E}(\log \xi_n)$

My attempt: I took $\sup_n \mathbb{E}$ on equation $(2)$ and find that RHS$<\infty$, by $(1)$,

and LHS $=\sup_n\mathbb{E} \sum_{j=1}^n P_n(1,j)\log P_n(1,j)^2\geq \sup_n\mathbb{E} \sum_{j=1}^n P_n(1,j)\log P_n(1,j) = \sup_n\mathbb{E} (\log \xi_n)$ and thus

$$\sup_n\mathbb{E} (\log \xi_n)<\infty$$

but how can I show that $$\lim_{M\to \infty}\sup_n\mathbb{E} (\log \xi_n.1_{\log \xi_n>M}) = 0$$to show uniform integrability of $\log \xi_n$? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An important fact is that the distribution of $\xi_n$ is given by (see Lemma $16$)
$$ \def \ex{\mathbb{E}} \ex[g(\xi_n)] = \ex \left[\sum_{j=1}^n P_n(1,j) g(P_n(1,j))\right].$$
Applying this with $g = \log^2$, we get
$$\begin{align}\ex\left[\log(\xi_n)^2\right]&= \ex \left[\sum_{j=1}^n P_n(1,j) \log(P_n(1,j))^2\right]\\
&\leq (\log \epsilon)^2+\sup_{p \in [0,\epsilon]} (\log p)^2 \ex \left[\sum_{j=1}^n P(1,j)^\beta\right] \\
&\leq (\log \epsilon)^2+\sup_{p \in [0,\epsilon]} (\log p)^2 \frac{1}{\lambda} \ex\left[\exp\left(\lambda \sum_{j=1}^n P_n(1,j)^\beta\right)\right],
\end{align}$$
where in the last inequality I used that $\lambda x \leq e^{\lambda x}$. Now taking the supremum yields
$$ \sup_n \ex\left[\log(\xi_n)^2\right] < \infty,$$
i.e. the family $(\log(\xi_n))_n$ is bounded in $L^2$. Thus it is uniformly integrable.